# Android game that runs on any size in an android device

Tags: android, size, device, any

I'm about to create a game in android that can run on any device (tablet, galaxy s). How can I make the game flexible? Particularly with the layouts, positions and sizes of the screen. I have no problem when it comes to images because `res` can handle it on the folders `hdpi`, `mdpi` and `ldpi`. thanks.

Comment: have you seen this ? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Please make your comment as an answer so I can check it and vote it up. Thanks! Thanks for the source! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen this ? [developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Sweet! I can even make it as a reference when developing an app not just in games.